# Calculate $\int_{0}^t (0.3(1+x)^3+0.7)^{-1/2}\,dx$

Tags: integration, hypergeometric-function, elliptic-integrals, beta-function

The following integral cannot be expressed in elementary terms:

> $\displaystyle\int_{0}^t \frac{1}{\sqrt{0.3(1+x)^3+0.7}}\,dx$
>   with $t>0$ real.

What are possible techniques for approaching this kind of integral, and how do they apply to this concrete case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral you posted [cannot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)) be [evaluated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) in terms of elementary functions. You will need either [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), [hypergeometric series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function), or [incomplete beta functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) to express it.

---

**Hypergeometric series:** It is quite simple, really, but there are a few details that we have to pay attention to: Basically, it all relies upon expanding the integrand into its [binomial series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series), then switching the order of summation and integration. The trick is that, in order for that to happen, the new variable has to be lesser than $1$ in absolute value. Notice that we can rewrite the integrand as $~\sqrt{\dfrac{10}7}\cdot\bigg(1+\dfrac37u^3\bigg)^{-1/2}~$ where *u* is $x+1$, and the new limits of integration are $1$ and $t+1$. Or $\sqrt{\dfrac{10}3}~u^{-3/2}\bigg(1+\dfrac73u^{-3}\bigg)^{-1/2}$ with the same limits in place. The former expression works for the case $|u|\le\sqrt[3]{\dfrac73}$ , and the latter when $|u|\ge\sqrt[3]{\dfrac73}$ . The whole idea is to place the relation of $\sqrt[3]{\dfrac73}>1$ with respect to $t+1$, and to break up the interval of integration accordingly $($if necessary$)$, then to employ the appropriate formula on each such subinterval.

---

**Incomplete beta functions:**

First, factor the free term outside the radical sign, then let $u=x+1$, and $v=\dfrac37u^3.~$ Finally, let $w=\dfrac1{v+1}$ . You will see the expression of the $($[incomplete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function#Incomplete_beta_function)$)$ [beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) slowly emerging from the mist of successive substitutions.